# Why does exec-maven-plugin run all phases twice?

Tags: maven

When I run a build with maven using the exec-maven-plugin, it runs everything twice for some reason. Is there a way to fix this so it only runs once? I've tried setting my phase in the pom.xml to compile and package and either way, it runs twice. My pom looks like

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>foo</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>bash</executable>
        <commandlineArgs>myscript.sh</commandlineArgs>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Which build phases are you running when building your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that adding the phase tag caused the command to get executed twice. Leaving that out, it is now getting run once as expected. I guess it doesn't matter what phase I give it now, it'll always run the goal, which works for me.

Comment: Instead of removing the phase.. you can pick a correct phase from https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

I move my execution part to compile pase... which got executed only during install phase..  if you want to run your task in compile phase.. below linke has the list
https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-structure.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run this early in the build, excluding the phase isn't an option.

You can do something like this instead in the plugin config:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default</id>
        <phase>none</phase> <!-- disable the default execution in validate phase -->
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>exec-do-something</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase><!-- now it will run once but in an earlier phase -->
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: This may work for <goal>java</goal> but it definitely doesn't work for <goal>exec</goal>.  The exec script still runs twice.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happening due to the inclusion of:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This seems to be that the `maven-source-plugin` causes a re-execution of the `generate-sources` phase. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html

> Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase generate-sources prior to executing itself.

If I removed this plugin, the `exec` goal only executed once.

Comment: Use the `jar-no-fork` goal instead of the `jar` goal.  The latter is for direct execution, rather than one tied into the normal lifecycle.  See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-no-fork-mojo.html -- "This goal functions the same as the jar goal but does not fork the build and is suitable for attaching to the build lifecycle."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the phase.. you can pick a correct phase from https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

I move my execution part to compile pase... which got executed only during install phase..  if you want to run your task in compile phase.. below linke has the list
https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-structure.html